# What is used to make online mockup for image processing

Tags: user-interface

What is used to make online mug mockup like [these](https://mediamodifier.com/product/white-mug-on-kitchen-background-mockup/393)?

Can it be done by connecting to Photoshop or is there a programming language for it?